# Basic calculator that calculates result based on operands using a class

Tags: python, object-oriented, calculator

Question:

> Create a basic calculator using classes that given 3 inputs - number 1, number 2 and operator -  calculates the result.

```
class calculator():

    def __init__(self,value1 , value2, operand):
        self.value1 = int(value1)
        self.value2 = int(value2)
        self.operand = operand

    def calculate (self):
        if self.operand == '+' :
            return self.value1 + self.value2

        if self.operand == '*':
            return self.value1 * self.value2

        if self.operand == '-' :
            return self.value1 - self.value2

        if self.operand == '/' :
            if self.value2 == 0:
                raise ZeroDivisionError
            else:
                return self.value1 / self.value2


r = calculator(6,7, '+')
print r.calculate()

r = calculator(3,7, '-')
print r.calculate()

r = calculator(6,0, '*')
print r.calculate()

r = calculator(9,5, '/')
print r.calculate()
```

How can i make this function better? Is this a correct implementation of a class?

Comment: What's the advantage of using a class like that, rather than using the math statements directly? Can you give us a use case/context where you plan to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule, if a class has two methods, one of which is the constructor, then it shouldn't be written as a class.  A simple `calculate(value1, value2, operand)` function would be better.

If you do write a class, then by [PEP 8 conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) it should be named `Calculator` instead.

I don't recommend the `int()` casts.  `print calculator(1.5, 3, '+').calculate()` would result in `4`, because `int()` performs truncation.  A good design would either produce `4.5` as expected, or raise an exception on validation failure.

Answer (score 2):

- There is no need to manually `raise ZeroDivisionError`. Python will do it for you anyway.
- Rather than inspecting an operand with the bunch of `if`s, create a dictionary of `operand, lambda`:

  ```
  ops = {
      '+': lambda x,y: x + y,
      ....
  }
  ```

  and calculate the result as

  ```
  ops[operand](value1, value2)
  ```

  Such dictionary (initialized in a constructor) is the only justification for making a class. It doesn't feel right to make an operator and values class members. Consider

  ```
  r = calculator()
  r.calculate(1, 2, '+')
  r.calculate(3, 4, '*')
  ```

  etc.